# oracle_fdw error while build on AIX 7.1

Tags: oracle, postgresql, build, aix, oracle-fdw

i have the following error while build the code of oracle_fdw-2.0.0 on AIX 7.1 using command : gmake

```
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -maix64  -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/sdk/include -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/oci/include -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/rdbms/public -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64 -I. -I./ -I/app/postgresql10ff/include/server -I/app/postgresql10ff/include/internal  -I/opt/freeware/include -I/usr/include  -c -o oracle_fdw.o oracle_fdw.c
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -maix64  -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/sdk/include -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/oci/include -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/rdbms/public -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64 -I. -I./ -I/app/postgresql10ff/include/server -I/app/postgresql10ff/include/internal  -I/opt/freeware/include -I/usr/include  -c -o oracle_utils.o oracle_utils.c
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -maix64  -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/sdk/include -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/oci/include -I/app/oracle/112/oradata/rdbms/public -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64 -I. -I./ -I/app/postgresql10ff/include/server -I/app/postgresql10ff/include/internal  -I/opt/freeware/include -I/usr/include  -c -o oracle_gis.o oracle_gis.c
rm -f liboracle_fdw.a
ar -X64 crs liboracle_fdw.a oracle_fdw.o oracle_utils.o oracle_gis.o
touch liboracle_fdw.a
/app/postgresql10ff/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/backend/port/aix/mkldexport.sh liboracle_fdw.a oracle_fdw.so >liboracle_fdw.exp
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -maix64  -o oracle_fdw.so liboracle_fdw.a -Wl,-bE:liboracle_fdw.exp -L/app/postgresql10ff/lib -Wl,-bbigtoc,-lm  -L/opt/freeware/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-blibpath:'/app/postgresql10ff/lib:/app/postgresql10ff/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib'  -Wl,-bnoentry -Wl,-H512 -Wl,-bM:SRE -L/app/oracle/112/oradata -L/app/oracle/112/oradata/bin -L/app/oracle/112/oradata/lib -lclntsh -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/11.1/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/11.1/client64/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client/lib -L/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64/lib -Wl,-bI:/app/postgresql10ff/lib/postgres.imp
ld: 0711-244 ERROR: No csects or exported symbols have been saved.
collect2: error: ld returned 8 exit status
/app/postgresql10ff/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/Makefile.shlib:326: recipe for target 'oracle_fdw.so' failed
gmake: *** [oracle_fdw.so] Error 1
gmake: *** Deleting file 'oracle_fdw.so'
```

appreciate your support to fix this issue.

Comment: I think you should use gcc-option `-shared` when creating a shared library. Also you should check your export-file (`liboracle_fdw.exp`) if it is empty or not.

Comment: hi ,
the content of the file is : #! oracle_fdw.so 
and how i use the -shared flag i used CFLAGS environment variable but didn't affect the gmake command

Comment: The export file shouldn't be empty; check your `/app/postgresql10ff/lib/pgxs/backend/port/aix/mkldexport.sh` script... Note: I've written some notes about export-files: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0017

Comment: I might have found this `mkldexport.sh` on the net (https://github.com/snaga/postgres95/blob/master/src/tools/mkldexport/mkldexport.sh)  -- well, it has way too many problems to list them.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond There is some more about this [in this Github issue](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/issues/267), and it looked like there were no global symbols in the shared object. Yet they are declared `extern` in the source.

Comment: You seem to ignore the links I offered :(